# Openresty: making two asynchronous tasks

Tags: nginx, lua, scalability, redirect, openresty

I am working on a issue with the design of a service which is basically redirection.

The request link I get will contain some params (abc.com/param1=v1&param2=v2).
I need to do two tasks on this link

1. I need to format the link and redirect user to another domain with
   some params passed(xyz.com/p1=v2) depending on the value of ,say,
   param1, This step should be as fast as possible
2. I need to save the link details to my DB after some processing.

I am planning to do this with nginx+lua(openresty)+(Redis or Mongodb?) combination.

As the two are unrelated task I am planning to split it, to do both asynchronously.

As the first task in a redirection, ngx.redirect("/link") seems apt for the case.
But the documentation says redirect call will terminates the processing of the current request

How can I make these two tasks independent and redirection will happen as fast a possible and should not wait for the completion of the second task.

Comment: Maybe store link details in some variable / table, redirect the user, then calmly process the data and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!. Can I make storing done by another thread and how give this job to another thread?

Comment: I don't even know, sorry :3

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make storing done by another thread and how give this job to another thread?

Yeah of course you easlt can, first of all you have to perfecctly understand the [Order of lua module directive](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2137369/15272097/77d1c09e-1a37-11e6-97ef-d9767035fc3e.png), then for make you Mongodb process in a ceperate thread you have to call in with [ngx.location.capture($url)](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture), where $url is the url in your location block :

```
location redirect/handling {
   ... // 
   content_by_lua_file url/to/your/code/forRedirectHandling
   ngx.location.capture(mongo/save):

}

location mongo/save {
  content_by_lua_file url/to/mongodbHandlingdCode
}
```

The ngx.location.capture() will point to your second location block and make your code in another thread (nginx worker).

Pls see the openresty documentation for know wich directive to use (access_by_lua, log_by_lua...)

hope this help :)

Comment: may I ask who's the author or source of that graphic "Order of lua module directive" I find it to be very educational and I would like to see more from the source. (a simple google search didn't get me any results)

Comment: The source of the graphic is the official github repository of the openresty /ngx-lua-module https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module

Comment: Hmm, I've been in that page dozens of times, not sure I how I missed it. Thanks